# how to Parse HTML encoded text from all rows in certain column in a csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Heres an image of how the data looks in the 'content' column:
[image: Heres an image of how the data looks in the 'content' column]

I loaded a csv file in pandas. In the column 'Content' each row contains html encoded text of varying lengths. Some are like 500+ words. My aim is to get rid of all the html encoding in all the rows of the column 'content'.

Could someone help get the code for this?

I only have this so far...

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('NuggetData.csv')
```

'Content' is the 9th column (if the first one is 0) in the table, and there are like 17,000 rows.

Example Text inside content column (this isn't the full text of row 1 either btw, its even longer):

**Row 1:**

```
<h2>A bold new toy commercial debuted last week, and it's got the internet talking.</h2><div><div data-reactroot="" class="push-wrapper--mobile" data-card="image"><img src="//i.upworthy.com/nugget/57e9536dca7292001f000008/attachments/toygif1-65977b573530a2407626f8a4aad22a4e.gif" class=""><div class="image-caption"><p>GIFs via Smyths Toys.</p></div></div></div><h2>In some ways, it was pretty standard because a boy's love for rocket ships isn't all that unique.</h2><div><div data-reactroot="" class="push-wrapper--mobile" data-card="image"><img src="//i.upworthy.com/nugget/57e953b8e2d8c7001f00002d/attachments/toygif2-6ef9ddacf2a56c63a84d773645450563.gif" class=""></div></div><h2>Neither is his love of Legos.</h2><div><div data-reactroot="" class="push-wrapper--mobile" data-card="image"><img src="//i.upworthy.com/nugget/57e95558e2d8c7002b000025/attachments/toygif4-4f0829dad2602f7dd6ed52813e6791a5.gif" class=""></div></div><h2>Plenty of boys like to (pretend to) drive motorcycles, too.</h2><div><div data-reactroot="" class="push-wrapper--mobile" data-card="image"><img src="//i.upworthy.com/nugget/57e95595ca72920034000029/attachments/toygif5-e1824fae63099796ac2947ba76ea185d.gif" class=""></div></div><h2>But ... playing dress-up as a queen in front of a crowd of cheering supporters?</h2><div><div data-reactroot="" class="push-wrapper--mobile" data-card="image"><img src="//i.upworthy.com/nugget/57e954c0e2d8c7002d00001e/attachments/toygif3-21ea60c5917fd80da817919c655a4c96.gif" class=""></div></div><p><em>That's</em> extraordinary. </p><h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use BeautifulSoup (library) and list comprehensions to parse your content column.

First you need to know what content you need from the HTML. I'm making some assumptions in order to explain:

1. You are looking for content in a DIV tag (`findAll('div')`)
2. Let say you are looking for the text inside the previous tag (`.text`)
3. You need the text from the third DIV tag (`[2]`)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

dataset['parsed_content'] = [bs(x,'lxml').findAll('div')[2].text for x in dataset['content']]
```

with the previous code you add a new column to the dataframe, in no case the content would be modified.

dependencies BeautifulSoup and lxml can be installed using pip.

Comment: I ran that code you sent, I get: IndexError: list index out of range,

Comment: @Azh588 would you expand your question with an example of some rows of the column 'content'. Make sure you adapt the code to your own case.

Comment: I attached a picture of how the text looks in the content column, Do you want to see more rows?

Comment: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?